# Problem in adding user controls to toolbox programatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Hi
I'm trying to add a new tab and my controls programatically to visual studio 2010.

Its creating tab but its not adding the controls to tab.

```
       //Getting design time environment
        DTE DesignTimeEnvironment = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0"), true);
        //Getting tool box object
        ToolBox VSToolBox = (ToolBox)DesignTimeEnvironment.Windows.Item("{B1E99781-AB81-11D0-B683-00AA00A3EE26}").Object;
        ToolBoxTab MyTab = null;
        string TabName = "MyComponents";


    //checkin if Tab already exists
    foreach (ToolBoxTab VSTab in VSToolBox.ToolBoxTabs)
    {
        if (VSTab.Name == TabName)
        {
            MyTab = VSTab;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If tab doesn't exist, creating new one
    if (null == MyTab)
        MyTab = VSToolBox.ToolBoxTabs.Add(TabName);

    MyTab.Activate();
    ToolBoxItem tbi = MyTab.ToolBoxItems.Add("FileBrowser",
    @"MyComponents.FileBrowser, MyTestComps, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2283de3658476795",
    vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);

    DesignTimeEnvironment.Quit();
```

If i run as administrator its working fine, adding Controls to control library,
but when I try to add the library which is not in GAC its not working. It doesn't through any exception.
Ex:

```
ToolBoxItem tbi = MyTab.ToolBoxItems.Add("FileBrowser",
    @"C:\MyComponents\MyTestComps.dll",
    vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine with the above code.
The only problem was I have to run the application as administrator rights.
Even this way also it is working.

```
ToolBoxItem tbi = MyTab.ToolBoxItems.Add("FileBrowser",
     @"C:\MyComponents\MyTestComps.dll",
     vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);
```

or 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quanto/archive/2009/06/12/how-do-i-deploy-a-toolbox-control-as-a-vsix.aspx