# Adding ToolBoxTab and ToolBoxItems in Visual Studio through an Add-In

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, visual-studio-addins

I have made my own control class by overriding base controls 
i.e.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TextBox runat=server></{0}:TextBox>")]
public class MyTextBox:System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
     public string myProperty {get;set;}
}
```

now for ease of use, what I do, is to Add these overridden controls in ToolBox window of the visual studio.

To do that, I simply do this.

1. Add a new Tab in ToolBox Window by right click and "Add Tab"
2. and then I do "Choose Items" (right click) and point to the dll of my control class.

All the controls that I have overridden i.e. TextBox, Button, Label appears there with the new name and icon. All I have to do is to drag them and use them.

Now, Is there a way, that my controls get loaded automatically? I mean I don't want to do above mentioned two steps.

See this is what I did.

1. Added an add-in and in its Exec, did this

   ```
   public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
       {
           handled = false;
           if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
           {
               if(commandName == "testAddin.Connect.testAddin")
               {
                   handled = true;
                   ToolBox tlBox = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.ToolBox;
                   ToolBoxTab tlBoxTab = null;
                   tlBoxTab = tlBox.ToolBoxTabs.Add("Test Controls");


                   tlBoxTab.Activate();
                   tlBoxTab.ToolBoxItems.Add("TestControls", @"C:\testLib.dll", vsToolBoxItemFormat.vsToolBoxItemFormatDotNETComponent);

          /////
            }
   ```

...but nothing happened. 'Test Controls' tab was there but no control. When I try to do same with 
System.Configuration.Install.dll ( found in [root]/Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework/[dotnetVersion]/) folder).. controls get loaded perfectly..but not when my custom control dll is being pointed.

please help me. I want to add those controls everytime IDE starts up (like telerik controls).
am new to this Extensibility Project Type of Visual Studio..

please help....

Comment: In case you haven't tried it yet this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977340/problem-in-adding-user-controls-to-toolbox-programatically) says running as administrator works.

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation here from the MSDN to automatically load items into the tool box. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166237

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual Studio Toolbox Manager](http://vstudiotoolbox.codeplex.com/). I have my own updated version for VS2010 (DTE for VS2010 is "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0").

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to deploy your control using a setup installer, I would suggest using the [Toolbox Controls Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286995%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which come with the Visual Studio SDK and can be easily integrated into Wix; this way, you could author your Wix setup project, include your assembly and just reference the aforementioned custom action for toolbox registration.